# Create HA PostgreSQL cluster

Tags: postgresql, clustering, high-availability, postgresql-9.2

We want to set up a highly available PostgreSQL cluster in our production environment. As of now, We have set up streaming replication. But we have to manually promote the slave as the master in case of failover and also change connection strings of the client applications.

Is there any tool exists for automating this? So that we don't have to promote the slave as master and also no connection string change requires in client applications.

We are using PostgreSQL-9.2.

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported an deprecated version? The easiest way to manage replicas is to use [repmgr](https://repmgr.org/)

Comment: We installed PostgreSQL on RHEL 7 using its repositories. and it installs PostgreSQL 9.2 by default. Also, the client wanted us to install PostgreSQL form RHEL repositories only.

Comment: That is stupid. 9.2 is not even maintained any more

Comment: I know its stupid, we tried to convince client but all in vain. Could you please suggest something for PostgreSQL 9.2

Comment: I already suggested [repmgr](https://repmgr.org/)

Comment: https://github.com/zalando/patroni is also a (very good) possibility.  (Note that the main contributors are sitting right behind me.  They told that with 9.2 it would possibly work, but it's better upgrading (see @a_horse_with_no_name 's first comment, too))

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : now our client is ready to upgrade from Postgres version 9.2 to 9.6. But we have Redhat Specific version on the production like rh-postgresql96 etc. Is it fine to go with this postgresql version?